# React routerv6 conditional Rendering of menus not working

Tags: reactjs

I want to conditionally Render the Menus.  It is displaying perfectly. But once login it takes me to /product url. But I get the error "[Product] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>". Please help. The following is my code:

```
My App.js 

`import './App.css';
import logo from './logo.svg';
//import { BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,Route,Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter,Routes,Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import HomePage from './components/HomePage';
import ViewProduct from './components/ViewProduct';
import Login from './components/Login';
import NavBar1 from './components/NavBar1';
import Product from './components/Product';
import DealerRegistration from './components/DealerRegistration';
import CreateProduct from './components/CreateProduct';
import Logout from './components/Logout';


import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faTrash,faEdit,faList,faHome,faSignIn,faSignOut,faCameraRetro,faBomb,faCoffee,faPeopleGroup } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import About from './components/About';
import DealerInfo from './components/DealerInfo';

import AuthenticatedRoute from './components/AuthenticatedRoute';
library.add(faTrash,faEdit,faList,faHome,faSignIn,faSignOut,faCameraRetro,faBomb,faCoffee,faPeopleGroup);

function App() {
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
       <h1>ProductHive</h1>
      </header>

      <section>
        <div style={{ backgroundImage: "url(/images/pms2.webp)",
                    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                    backgroundSize:'cover', minHeight:'140vh',minWidth:'100vw'}}> 
         <BrowserRouter>
              <NavBar1></NavBar1>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<HomePage/>} />           
              <Route path='/aboutus' element={<About/>}/>
                           
              <Route path="/product" element={<><AuthenticatedRoute><Product/></AuthenticatedRoute></>} />
              <Route path="/logout" element={<><AuthenticatedRoute><Logout/></AuthenticatedRoute></>} />
              <Route path="/dealers" element={<><AuthenticatedRoute><DealerInfo/></AuthenticatedRoute></>} />
             
              <Route path='/register' element={<DealerRegistration/>} />
              <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>} />
               
              <Route path='/viewProduct/:id' element={<ViewProduct/>}/>
              <Route path='/addProduct/:id' element={<CreateProduct/>} />  
                
            </Routes>
           </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
      </section>

       <footer className='footer'>
        <p>&copy; All Right Reserved to ProductHive</p>
      </footer> 
    </div>
  );
};`
export default App;
```

```
NavBar1.js 

import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
import '../style/NavBar1.css';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthenticationService from "../service/AuthenticationService";

const isUserLoggedIn = AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn();
const NavBar1 = () => {

    
    return(
        <nav className="navbar">
            <ul className="nav-list">
                <li className="nav-item">
                {isUserLoggedIn &&    <Link to="/" className="nav-link">
                        <span>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="home"></FontAwesomeIcon>  
                        </span> &nbsp;
                        Home</Link>} {/* <a href='/'> */}
                </li>

                <li className="nav-item">
                {!isUserLoggedIn &&  <Link to="/register" className="nav-link">
                        <span>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="camera-retro"></FontAwesomeIcon>  
                        </span> &nbsp; 
                        Register</Link>}
                </li>

                <li className="nav-item">
                {!isUserLoggedIn &&   <Link to="/login" className="nav-link">
                    <span>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="sign-in"></FontAwesomeIcon>  
                    </span> &nbsp; 
                    Login</Link>}
                </li>

                <li className="nav-item">
                {isUserLoggedIn &&  <Link to="/product" className="nav-link">
                    <span>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="bomb"></FontAwesomeIcon>  
                    </span> &nbsp; 
                        Products</Link>}
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                {isUserLoggedIn &&  <Link to="/logout" className="nav-link" onClick={AuthenticationService.logout}>
                    <span>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="sign-out"></FontAwesomeIcon>  
                    </span> &nbsp; 
                       Logout</Link>}
                </li>

                <li className="nav-item">
                {!isUserLoggedIn &&    <Link to="/aboutus" className="nav-link">
                    <span>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="coffee"></FontAwesomeIcon>  
                    </span> &nbsp; 
                       About Us</Link>}
                </li>

                <li className="nav-item">
                {isUserLoggedIn &&   <Link to="/dealers" className="nav-link">
                    <span>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="people-group"></FontAwesomeIcon>  
                    </span> &nbsp; 
                       Dealers Info</Link>}
                </li>
                
                </ul>
        </nav>
    );
}
export default NavBar1;
```

```
********* AithenticatedRoute.js************

import React from 'react';
import { Route,Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthenticationService from '../service/AuthenticationService';

const AuthenticatedRoute = (props) => {
  if (AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
    return <Routes><Route {...props} /></Routes>;
  } else {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }
};

export default AuthenticatedRoute;
```

I tried changing the Authentication Route but still did not succeed

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the `<Outlet />` component imported from `react-router-dom`.

Based on the condition the `<Outlet />` component will let the user proceed to the child routes.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Outlet  } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthenticationService from '../service/AuthenticationService';

const AuthenticatedRoute = (props) => {
const isAuthenticated = AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn();
  
    return isAuthenticated? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
 
  
};

export default AuthenticatedRoute;
```

Another important thing to do is place the `const isUserLoggedIn = AuthenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()` inside your `NavBar1` component in order to the condition to be checked every time the component renders.